Left Censoring has no impact on the outcome of Survival function Surv()?
Im am using Survival Analysis to analyze the processes of detection for various species of crustaceans and molluscs in the Mediterranean Sea.
For each I have two Datasets "alien" probably entering the basin after the opening of the Suez Canal and "native" who have been there before.
For the natives I use 1758 (Systema Naturae by Linné) as a birth. The time of detection as death = event.
For aliens I use left censoring (so no birth) and as well the time of first detection as death = event.
However I was playing around with my data and tried 1869 (opening of the Suez Canal) as a birth for alien species.
But the outcome of the survival curve would be identical (except for one is a time period while the other is a date) whether I handle the data as left censored or not. Why?
# surv_object uncensored
time <- xdata$Survival_Time ;  status <- xdata$Survival_Status ; survob <- Surv(time, status) 

kmfit <- survfit(survob ~ 1) ; kmfit
Call: survfit(formula = survob ~ 1)

      n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,] 65     65    120      99     135

# surv_object left censored
time <- xdata$Year_publ_first ; status <- xdata$Survival_Status ; survob <- Surv(time, status, type = "left") 
kmfit <- survfit(survob ~ 1) ; kmfit

Call: survfit(formula = survob ~ 1)

     records  n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
[1,]      65 66     66   1989    1968    2004


